# How does vim know to syntax-color .hgrc?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, mercurial

With `syntax on`, vim syntax-highlights my `~/.hgrc` file.

- How does vim recognize this file?
- How can I get vim to apply the same syntax coloring to a differently-named file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vim uses a runtime script (such as `/usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim`) which checks the filename, matches it in this case as

```
" Mercurial config (looks like generic config file)
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.hgrc,*hgrc              setf cfg
```

The script is documented here: *[Vim documentation: filetype](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html)*

You can customize your environment using similar commands (in fact the documentation recommends that you do this rather than modify the installed `filetype.vim`).  vim's documentation refers to this as an "autocommand", and its documentation is the best place to start reading about the feature: *[Vim documentation: autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)*